# Python: how to use type hints in conjunction with `__instancecheck__`

Tags: python, python-typing

Let me build my question step-by-step using a silly example: I have a function `roast(obj)` that works on objects that are *ducks*, i.e., anything that "can quack":

```py
def roast(obj):
    print(f"<< {obj.quack()} >> the duck said, before being roasted\n - The (sad) end.")
```

I want to improve the function by checking that the object is a duck before anything else. To facilitate checking if `obj` is a duck, I wrote the following:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta


class DuckMeta(ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        return callable(getattr(instance, "quack", None))


class Duck(metaclass=DuckMeta):
    def quack(self):
        return "Quack!"
```

The `__instancecheck__` method in the meta-class implements the logic to check if `instance` is a duck, and the class `Duck` is, well, a very basic duck class. Great, now I can update `roast()`:

```py
def roast(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, Duck):
        raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(obj)} is not a duck!")
    print(f"<< {obj.quack()} >> the duck said, before being roasted\n - The (sad) end.")
```

Neat! In the interpreter I can now do:

```
>>> roast(Duck())
<< Quack! >> the duck said, before being roasted
 - The (sad) end.
>>> roast([1, 2, 3])
TypeError: Object of type <class 'list'> is not a duck!
```

The code is cool, but what if I decide to roast Spanish or French ducks? Well, here you go, in two different ways:

```py
class Pato(Duck):
    def quack(self):
        return "¡Cua, cua, cua!"


class Canard:
    # Not using inheritance here is intentional!
    def quack(self):
        return "Coin-coin!"
```

Which can both be used as:

```
>>> roast(Pato())
<< ¡Cua, cua, cua! >> the duck said, before being roasted
 - The (sad) end.
>>> roast(Canard)
<< Coin-coin! >> the duck said, before being roasted
 - The (sad) end.
```

All looks good. However, I want to go the extra mile and add type hints to my function. And here arise the question: is there a "correct" way to do it? If I simply change the function into `def roast(obj: Duck)`, when calling `roast(Canard())` my IDE (PyCharm) warns me with:

> Expected type 'Duck', got 'Canard' instead

which makes me believe that this is not the correct way of adding typing to the function. What should I do instead?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right way to do this. You should have a `Quackable` abstract base class, and mix that into all your classes.

Comment: Absolutely fair comment! However, in my real code base I am dealing with a bunch of classes from existing libraries. I could just subclass them, inheriting both from the original class and my `Duck` interface, but I think it's over-complicating a (probably) simple task. Do you see a good solution given the additional constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the structural typing approach via [`typing.Protocol`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)

```py
from typing import Protocol


class Quackable(Protocol):
    def quack(self) -> str:
        ...


def roast(obj: Quackable):
    ...
```

References:

- https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/
- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html

Comment: Provided that you do run a static type check on your code, you can get rid of all the runtime instance checks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I started skimming the PEP and seems just what I need! I'll give it a more thorough read ASAP and come back to (hopefully) mark the question as answered or to add comments.